# Height of listview gets three times than the list items ,leaving the remaining space of the listview blank in bottom in android

Tags: android, listview

there is problem in my listview in terms of the design, as it leaves me in making some extra space in bottom,the actual problem is that i am using multiple listviews in a single activity,and then control the height of each listview by using this code :-

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView,Context c) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) 
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
      //  Toast.makeText(c, "height:-"+totalHeight, 0).show();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    Toast.makeText(c, "height:-"+ params.height, 0).show();

    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

and it works fine for ,when i am loading data from json online,but when i am using my data offline from the sqlite database it increases the height of the listview unwantedly to three times of the items height ,i have googled a lot but doesnt get anything ,if anybody has some idea ,please let me know i can explain a bit more.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Breaking News"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@android:id/list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:background="#F45555"
                            android:text="Top Stories"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:background="#F45555"
                            android:text="City"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="News"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/white" >
                        </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Kashmir"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/white" >
                        </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#F45555" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/category1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#F45555"
                            android:text="Jammu"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:background="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I also have experienced this kind of issue. Based from my experience, it was caused by using `TableLayout` for child view, thus I have to change it to `LinearLayout`. However, I still don't know why did it happen. However, I doubt my case also applies to you...

Comment: yes You are right ,but i am using LinearLayout not TableTayout

Comment: Try setting them to each have wrap_content for their heights, and don't change the height programatically.  Then give each a weight of 1.  Then try to adjust the weight until you get what you want.

Comment: @RickFalck, I have tried it as well but it wraps the contents and shows a single listItem for each listview, as i again want to say that i am using mulitiple listviews in a single activity layout,see my xml file i am going to post that file as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Breaking News"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#F45555"
        android:text="Top Stories"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#F45555"
        android:text="City"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="News"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Kashmir"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#F45555" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#F45555"
        android:text="Jammu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but i doesn't works for me ,i get the only alternative of setting size statically in XML files height attribute

Comment: OK.  I can't really tell what you are trying to do without pictures.

Answer (score 0):

please debug the data you are getting from the remote.It make contain extra spaces.